# How to extend the height of a scroll bar in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a scroll bar and placed it inside the ListBox. I want it to extend all the way to the bottom of the ListBox but i cannot find a way to extend it. What i saw people do was

```
.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

but for me it stays in the top left and doesnt extend itself. Here is the code for it, all help is appreciated.

```
taskBox = Frame(setBox,bg="#1B2834")
taskBox.configure(width=1100,height=625)
taskBox.place(x=5,y=5)

taskList = Listbox(setBox, bg="#1B2834")
taskList.configure(width=183,height=39)
taskList.place(x=5,y=5)

taskScroll = Scrollbar(taskList)
taskScroll.configure(bg="#1B2834",width=18)
taskScroll.place(x=1080,y=0)
```

Comment: You should be using `grid` or `pack`, not `place`. Do you really need to use `place`, or are you using it simply because you don't know how to use the other choices?

Comment: @BryanOakley i only went to use place because, like i said, ".pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
stays in the top left and doesnt extend itself."

Comment: Try `place(relx=1, y=0, relheight=1, anchor='ne')`.  But why do you put the scrollbar inside the listbox? Why don't you put it next to the listbox instead?

Comment: @acw1668 that works thank you. How i have my layout set up it just looked cleaner to place it inside the listbox

Comment: If you place it in the listbox, the scrollbar will hide some text that is at the right margin of the listbox. If you want the appearance of the scrollbar being in the listbox then you should put the listbox and scrollbar inside a frame. You can then turn the border off of the listbox and use the frame to provide the border.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using *only* `pack()` since, `place()` and `pack()` cannot co-exist I believe.

Comment: i know that they cannot coexist but the issue is that if i use ".pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
 it stays in the top left and doesnt extend itself."